# How to get the LaTeX beamer template from Overleaf?

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

As the title, I try to copy the template from Overleaf, for example this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/3471173tsxnjg#/9817206/). But I can't run it in my computer! How to solve this problem, or which website could download the available template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't copy but download the entire folder as `.zip`. Click `PROJECT` and then you will get `Download as ZIP` in the side bar (you may choose `input files only` BTW).

[image]

Once you download `zip`, unzip the contents in to a folder and then the file will compile as all dependencies will be inside that folder.